# Is it possible to free a required module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

When you `import` a file in nodejs, it's loaded, evaluated and cached.

Is it possible to free the memory for that file, if you know you will never use it again (or maybe in a long time, worth it to compile it again).

What I want to do is importing a temporal file, read its code, execute it once and then free it forever (I know it's not going to be used again, and I don't want to have memory leaks)

Basically is having dynamic code in nodejs.

Pages like [codility](https://www.codility.com/) which allows you to input code and execute in backend side, should work with a similar solution... unless they run a complete new nodejs instance with that code... and then kill it.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete from the module cache like this. Just make sure that there are no circular dependencies or the module will not actually be freed from memory

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./theModuleYouWantToDelete.js')]
```

Comment: Exactly what I just discovered!
But thanks for the code chunk! :D

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "free" the module.  Nodejs does not have a way to remove the code once it has been run so that will always remain in memory.

If you remove all references to the module (by deleting it from the cache) and removing any other references there might be to exported data, then any data associated with the module should be eligible for garbage collection.

For a service that lets the user run arbitrary code on the server, I would always run that in a sandboxed separate process where you can kill the process and recover all resources used by the code, not run that in the main server process.

Comment: any method to get modules imported but any other modules? to free them too

Comment: @danikaze - I have no  idea what that comment means.

Comment: if module A is included by me, but A includes B, is there a way to know that B is also included? If not, probably even if I free module A I won't be able to free B properly (because I don't know about its existence)

Comment: @danikaze - No.  As I've tried to indicate to you, the whole notion of trying to "free" a module is just a faulty design in the first place.  It is not part of the nodejs design.  Run these in a separate process where you can shut down the process to get everything cleaned up.

Comment: yeah well, sorry for asking =_=

Comment: @danikaze - Asking is OK, but the actual answer to get proper cleanup is to run them in a separate process.  No matter what you do in the same process, you won't be unloading the code, you won't be undoing any global things the module has done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reading the [NodeJS documentation about modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache), it happens to exist a public `cache` member and it says:

> Modules are cached in this object when they are required. By deleting a key value from this object, the next require will reload the module. This does not apply to native addons, for which reloading will result in an error.
>
> Adding or replacing entries is also possible. This cache is checked before native modules and if a name matching a native module is added to the cache, no require call is going to receive the native module anymore. Use with care!

So I guess every evaluated module lives here internally, and removing a key from this object like the docs says, it will also free the related memory to that portion of code (when the garbage collector do its job)